# The Keycloak Google Identity Provider doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, keycloak

I have been trying to add a Keycloak Google Identity Provider. For this, I have been following the official docs ([Social Identity Providers > Google](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#google)). Besides, I have tried lots of other tutorials from many blog sites and Youtube. However, every time the following error pops up (annoying already):

> [image]

I can't figure out the reason for this. I'm using the Node.js adapter.

> Meanwhile, the GitHub identity provider works fine.

*The sequence of instructions that works correctly is definitely awarded with bounty. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Did you went through configuring Cloud Identity? as stated in [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/keycloak-single-sign-on#configuring_cloud_identity)

Comment: Hello can you please tell me how provide idp login with Node.js adapter?

Comment: How you integrated GitHub identity provider login with node.js adapter as I have checked that there is no option to idphint in node.js adapter